# Add <code> element with text from class name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I need help adding a `<code>` element that contains the text of a specific class name.

This is my base markup:

```
<div class="ctnr">
    <div class="up-triangle"></div>
</div>
```

It should look like this after adding the `<code>` element which in turns has its sibling's element's class name:

```
<div class="ctnr">
    <code class='info'>.up-triangle</code>
    <div class="up-triangle"></div>
</div>
```

I am able to add the `<code>` element via `.prepend()`:

```
$("<code class='info'></code>").prependTo(".ctnr");
```

Here's a fiddle I created so far: http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/ywtpz8a0/1/

I just can't figure out how to add the text of its sibling `DIV`'s class into the injected `<code>` element.

I know there is a `.text()` and `.attr()` functions but I can't wrap my head around how to use them, I'm positive it can be accomplished in some way with those functions.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ywtpz8a0/5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a loop, assuming there's more than one `.ctnr`:

```js
$(".ctnr").each(function() {
  var code = $("<code>").addClass("info").text($(this).find("div").attr("class"));
  code.prependTo(this);
});
```

```html
<div class="ctnr">
  <div class="up-triangle"></div>
</div>
<div class="ctnr">
  <div class="up-square"></div>
</div>
<div class="ctnr">
  <div class="up-circle"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @TJ, yes, your assumption is correct, I do have more than one `.ctnr`. Your solution works as intended. This part is what I didn't know: `.text($(this).find("div").attr("class"));` Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Forgot to mention that since I needed the `.` from the class name, I added it to the `.text()` method, like this: `.text("." + $(this).find("div").attr("class"));`

Answer (score 3):

If there is single element with `ctnr` class:

```
$('<code />')
    .addClass('info')
    .text($('.ctnr').find('div').attr('class'))
    .prependTo('.ctnr');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ywtpz8a0/7/

**EDIT**

If there are multiple elements with `ctnr` class:

```
$('.ctnr').each(function () {
    $('<code />')
        .addClass('info')
        .text($(this).find('div').attr('class'))
        .prependTo($(this));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ywtpz8a0/8/

Comment: Thanks for the edit. However, your solution is adding the `.ctnr` class name not the sibling's class name. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I don't see any updates on any of the answers. Whatever you did it still adding the `ctnr` class.

Comment: That works very well now. I made a small improvement and added the `.` to the class name: http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/ywtpz8a0/9/. Gave you an upvote. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Don't pretend. Try prepend.

```js
window.addElement = function() {
  $('.ctnr').prepend("<code class='info'>." + $('.ctnr').find('div').attr('class') + "</code>");
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ctnr">
    <div class="up-triangle"></div>
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="addElement()">Add Element</button>
```

Comment: Although I'm not using a button to create new containers, this is certainly a creative answer :). Thanks for your help.